# Error when trying to open an android project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I opened an android project for

```
4.1.2 API 16 minimum required SDK: API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo) Target SDK:API19: Android 4.4 (kitkat) compile with: Google API's (google inc.) (API 19)
```

but when generating i have an Error: in the appcompat_v7 folder (which i have no idea why it is there)

there is an error in the res folder in the **values-v21** folder in the **styles_base.xml**:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
   parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
</style>
```

this is the code and the error is:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given 
name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
```

I have no idea what's happening and i will be happy if someone can solve it to me so i can move on and build an app.

P.S I think I was specific enough but this is my first post in stack overflow so if you still have questions just ask.

Comment: It is having trouble finding `android:Widget.Material.ActionButton`. Have you tried replacing it?

Comment: actually i can't see any button in the graphical view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've tried to close and reopen Eclipse?  Sometimes this happens to me and that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you select wrong android api in project properties.
Rigth mouse click on project -> Properties-> Android-> ***Select "Android 4.4.2"*** **not** **"Google API 4.4.2"**

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: first of all, it wasn't google API 4.4.2 it was 4.1.2 and i tried to change it to 4.4.2 and it still won't work